# php - can google crawler detect meta tags in if statement

Tags: php, meta

I have a template webpage that has a fixed header / footer.  Depending on a body content to display, I need to change the content of meta tags in the the head.

After some googling, I learned that google crawler doesn't run any javascript codes and read php variables in pages. If so, will google crawler detect the following meta tags ignoring if statements?

```
<?php if(about page) ?>
    <meta ...>
    <meta ...>
    <meta ...>
<?php } else if(contact page) { ?>
    <meta ...>
    <meta ...>
    <meta ...>
<?php } and so on... ?>
```

Comment: Short answer no! Long answer, as you are using an if/else clause, the body of the HTTP content rendered will not contain the failing section of the if/else. Thus will never be there to be crawled.

Comment: Google’s crawler is a _client_ like any other – like f.e. a _browser_. Price question: Does a normal _browser_ see your PHP code …?

Comment: @CBroe Yeah... your price question totally makes sense. I guess I need to have multiple head tags in separate php files and include one of them depending on the current uri a client is accessing.

Comment: Your guess sounds like your answer to the price question was wrong already … let me re-phrase it: _What_ is it that a browser/any client gets to see? Answer (so that we don’t have to play this game all day long): The _output_ of your PHP script. Now the new prize question (double-or-nothin’) – what _is_ the output of the snippet shown above? (Assuming those were valid if statements.)

Comment: meta tags?  Urggg... am I completely misunderstanding something here? If I use URI something like - http://www.sample.com/about  for if statements to include a php file with appropriate meta tags in html header, wouldn't  the meta tags be readable to crawlers? :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the way you've worded your question, as well as some of your comments, it sounds as though you're missing something very important.

PHP directives (like `<?php if ...?>`) are interpreted **by the server**. HTTP clients, such as web browsers and crawlers, only see the output of these directives; content that is not generated as output (e.g, because it is skipped by an `if`/`else`) is never sent to the client at all, so they cannot possibly detect it.

Comment: I need to do more research on this topic... :(